# A Very Weird Day

Tags: riddle

Today was a very weird day for me.
 First, I saw a rainbow with the colors white, pink, yellow, green, blue, beige, and orange.
 Then, I drove my car across the sea.
 Finally, I saw a dog convicted of a crime and then almost immediately pardoned.
 My friends were with me the whole time, but so were Charles, George and Edward, who are not my friends. However, I do know their last name. 

Do you?

Comment: Worth pointing out that (if the answer is correct), the second clue may or may not make sense depending on where the reader grew up.

Comment: @SPM Where did you grow up where it doesn't make sense?

Comment: @paste In Australia, we don't have seas on our board, only famous Australian streets, landmarks and utilities, so it wouldn't immediately come to mind.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Charles, George, and Edward have the last name:

> [Parker Brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parker_Brothers)

Today you:

> Played Monopoly.

First, I saw a rainbow with the colors white, pink, yellow, green, blue, beige, and orange.

> These are the colours of the money.
>  [image: Monopoly Money]

Then, I drove my car across the sea.

> The car and the ship are pieces that travel on the same track.
>  [image]
>
>  This clue could also pertain to the spaces (which are all named after streets in Atlantic City, NJ) have the names of bodies of water. (Atlantic, Pacific, Baltic, Mediterranean)
>
>
>  The asker has commented that he meant that the first space after the Go space is Baltic which is named after a sea.

Finally, I saw a dog convicted of a crime and then almost immediately pardoned.

> The dog got sent to jail (Go to Jail Space? or other card) and then either payed his bail or had a get out of jail free card.
>  [image]

Comment: Is there a new version of this or something? Half of these hints don't make sense with the original

Comment: @gannolloy The rainbow is the money

Comment: Makes sense now +1

Comment: I updated the answer with some more details.

Comment: Sea hint could also refer to Atlantic or pacific

Comment: Or Baltic/Mediterranean.

Comment: Sure, I added it.

Comment: I think the "sea" refers to driving through *Atlantic* City, nothing more.

Comment: Well done! I figured someone on here would make the connection quickly, but I thought it might be a fun head-scratcher for the rest :) For the record, what I had in mind for driving the car across the sea was that my piece was the car and the first space on the board has the name of a sea.

Comment: You can also get out of jail by rolling a double (ex. both die land on 5) within your next 3 turns :D

Comment: @trevor You can also go to jail in other ways.  I didn't want to copy the entire monopoly ruleset for my answer :D

Comment: The fact that one of the pieces is a cruise ship now could also go along with "the sea".  (Pretty sure that's a new piece?  I remember they got rid of the guy-on-a-horse and replaced it with something...)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It's actually a battleship, see the pic in my answer.

Comment: @LeppyR64 - Yes, I was referring to said pic, it just kind of looked like it could be a cruise ship.  On closer inspection, I can see that it does have guns on it, so I guess battleship is more accurate.  Point is, whatever kind of ship it is, you'd likely find it out at sea, and in Monopoly, you might drive your car right next to it...

Comment: On behalf of @SPM: "Worth pointing out that if this answer is correct, the second clue may or may not make sense depending on where the reader grew up."